# How to store multiple UIImages within each index of an array of UIImages in Swift 2.0?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, uiimage

first I apologize if the title is not descriptive. Please free feel to change it more appropriate to my issue.

So basically, I have an array of `UIImages` called **eventImages**.

In obj-C, I declared it and initialized it like so:

```
NSArray *eventImages;

eventImages = @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"lion_dance.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"ivan_cheong.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"tien_nguyen.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"step_up.jpg"],
                         @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"dj_happee.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"adam_cease.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"ao_dai.jpg"] ],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"california_summer.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"question_mark"] ];
```

As you can see, at the 4th index, I am able to store an inner array `UIImages`.

I would like to achieve this in Swift 2.0

Here's what I've done so far:

```
var eventImages: [UIImage]?

eventImages = [UIImage(named: "lion_dance.jpg")!, 
UIImage(named: "ivan_cheong.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "tien_nguyen.jpg")!,   
UIImage(named: "step_up.jpg")!, [UIImage(named: "dj_happee.jpg")!, 
UIImage(named: "adam_cease.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "ao_dai.jpg")!], 
UIImage(named: "california_summer.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "question_mark")!]
```

However, the compiler is giving me the error:

> Contextual type 'UIImage' cannot be used with array literal

How can I achieve in Swift what I achieved in Obj-C?

Thanks

Comment: hello @Pangu follow my code. its working correctly.

Comment: If facing any problem then let me know.

Comment: have u got solutions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like:

```
var eventImages = [UIImage(named: "lion_dance.jpg")!, 
UIImage(named: "ivan_cheong.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "tien_nguyen.jpg")!,   
UIImage(named: "step_up.jpg")!, [UIImage(named: "dj_happee.jpg")!, 
UIImage(named: "adam_cease.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "ao_dai.jpg")!], 
UIImage(named: "california_summer.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "question_mark")!]
```

If you declare array type to by `UIImage` you cannot add array of `UIImage` (`[UIImage]`) because type is different. However if you skip type declaration, Swift will figure it out and allow this array to exist.

The type of array would be `NSObject` I think, then you can just cast it to access images:

```
class SomeClass {

    var eventImages = [[UIImage()], UIImage(), UIImage(), UIImage(), [UIImage(), UIImage(), UIImage()]]

    func doSomething() {
        if let singleImage = eventImages[1] as? UIImage {
            // Access single image
        }
        if let imageArray = eventImages[4] as? [UIImage] {
            // Access image array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need eventImages to be global so I can access it in other functions?..that's why I declared it as a `UIImage` type underneath the class name

Comment: I really do not see why you cannot declare it in your class scope like property then.

Comment: I'm new to this so I apologize, but I do not understand?

Comment: is there a simpler way to achieve this without creating an inner class?

Comment: Don't create inner class :) use it in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can Follow the below steps to store multiple images in array Swift 2.0 like this,

--->  First prepare or declare array object like,

```
var eventImages : NSArray = NSArray()
```

---> Now Store whatever images u want in your array object like,

```
    eventImages = ["1.png","2.png","3.png", NSArray(objects: "4.png", "5.png")]
```

---> Now Check whether its array or string in array and get image name and assigned it to image view

```
    if let arr = eventImages.objectAtIndex(2) as? NSString   // means it check whether its string 
    {
         self.imgVIew.image = UIImage(named: arr as String)
    }
    else // if not string then take from array like this 
    {
        self.imgVIew.image = UIImage(named: eventImages.objectAtIndex(3).objectAtIndex(1) as! String)
    }
```

I hope you get your image and assign it to image view...enjoy..it

Comment: I dont want to assign it to an image view, I only want to have access to the UIImages in the array, and have access to multiple UIImages within a "specific" index in the array.

Comment: I Just show that uiimage by assigning it to image view but you can do whatever u want.

Comment: in if true section, you get image based on particular index of images array and in else section, you can get array so perform whatever u want. its work perfectly for me.